# Function to replace occurrence of certain characters with --[character]-- in a given string

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I replace every occurrence of a character in a string with `--[character]--` in `es6` preferably.

Example string: `tb23a`

Pattern: `t3a`

Expected output: `--t--b2--3----a--`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function replaceEveryChar(value, options) {
  const { chars = '', leading = '', trailing = '' } = options;
  return (chars && String(value).replace(

    RegExp(`\[${ chars }\]`, 'g'),
    match => `${ leading }${ match }${ trailing }`

  )) || value;
}

console.log(
  "replaceEveryChar('tb23a', { chars: 't3a', leading: '--', trailing: '--' }) ...",
  replaceEveryChar('tb23a', { chars: 't3a', leading: '--', trailing: '--' })
);
console.log(
  "replaceEveryChar('tb23a', { chars: 'b2', leading: '*', trailing: '+' }) ...",
  replaceEveryChar('tb23a', { chars: 'b2', leading: '*', trailing: '+' })
);

console.log(
  "replaceEveryChar('foobar', { leading: '*', trailing: '+' }) ...",
  replaceEveryChar('foobar', { leading: '*', trailing: '+' })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```